# Foreach a large JSON

Tags: c#, json, serialization, foreach

How can I use foreach in this Json, I try with multiple foreach but I can't do it, I want just retrieve the coordinates data.

For the moment this is my code to retrieve the data and this code doesn't work, I get an error : (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty' does not contain a definition for 'coordinates').

```
String toto = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
dynamic jsonn = JValue.Parse(toto);
dynamic deserializedValue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(toto);


                foreach (var data in deserializedValue.resourceSets)
                {
                    foreach (var data1 in data.resources)
                    {
                        foreach (var data2 in data1.point)
                        {
                            foreach (var data3 in data2.coordinates)
                            {
                                var message = new MessageDialog("Coord: " + data3.coordinates);
                                await message.ShowAsync();
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

---

```
{
  "authenticationResultCode": "ValidCredentials",
  "brandLogoUri": "http:\/\/dev.virtualearth.net\/Branding\/logo_powered_by.png",
  "copyright": "Copyright © 2016 Microsoft and its suppliers. All rights reserved. This API cannot be accessed and the content and any results may not be used, reproduced or transmitted in any manner without express written permission from Microsoft Corporation.",
  "resourceSets": [
    {
      "estimatedTotal": 1,
      "resources": [
        {
          "__type": "Location:http:\/\/schemas.microsoft.com\/search\/local\/ws\/rest\/v1",
          "bbox": [
            41.298164367675781,
            -5.2461638450622559,
            51.099018096923828,
            9.6006984710693359
          ],
          "name": "France",
          "point": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
              46.637279510498047,
              2.3382623195648193
            ]
          },
          "address": {
            "countryRegion": "France",
            "formattedAddress": "France"
          },
          "confidence": "High",
          "entityType": "CountryRegion",
          "geocodePoints": [
            {
              "type": "Point",
              "coordinates": [
                46.637279510498047,
                2.3382623195648193
              ],
              "calculationMethod": "Rooftop",
              "usageTypes": [
                "Display"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "matchCodes": [
            "Good"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "statusCode": 200,
  "statusDescription": "OK",
  "traceId": "80d14996537e49218145ff171faeca00|BN20130533|02.00.164.1500|BN2SCH020171462, i-42be63df.us-east-1b, i-e3280660.us-east-1b, BN2SCH020201258"
}
```

Comment: I love the availability of "dynamic", but this is a code smell to me. I'm hard pressed to find many uses for dynamic EXCEPT for the way up to the client, where I find it's quite convenient; but typically confine my use to that pattern. For working with objects in this fashion, I might suggest are more concrete schema to represent your nodes. Intellisense would have picked your problem up before compilation was even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`point` is an object, not an array.

```
"point": {       // <- Notice the '{'
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          46.637279510498047,
          2.3382623195648193
        ]
      },
```

Here is how you read it :

```
foreach (var set in deserializedValue.resourceSets)
{
    foreach (var resource in set.resources)
    {
        foreach (var coord in resource.point.coordinates)
        {
            var message = new MessageDialog("Coord: " + coord);
            await message.ShowAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the structure:

```
{    <---layer #1
    "authenticationResultCode": "ValidCredentials",
    "brandLogoUri": "http:\/\/dev.virtualearth.net\/Branding\/logo_powered_by.png",
    "copyright": "Copyright ...",
    "resourceSets": [  <-- layer #2
        { <-- layer #3
            "estimatedTotal": 1,
            "resources": [ <-- layer #4
                {  <-- layer #5
                      "__type": "Location:http:\/\/schemas.microsoft.com\/search\/local\/ws\/rest\/v1",
                      "bbox": [
                            41.298164367675781,
                            -5.2461638450622559,
                            51.099018096923828,
                            9.6006984710693359
                      ],
                      "name": "France",
                      "point": {  <--layer #6
                      "type": "Point",
                      "coordinates": [
```

`coordinates` is 6 layers down, and you've got 4 layers of un-nesting in yoru code.